# what does "consensus call" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain what "consensus call" means in this sentence for me -
To be sure, a recession is not the consensus call on Wall Street, with projections in recent days showing increased optimism?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **consensus** is when most people agree on a decision.
A **call** (in market terms) is a forecast on the future.

A **consensus call** is the **same** market call made by a majority of market watchers (analysts, strategists, portfolio managers).  Having a consensus leads to **herding** where most market participants will do the same thing at the same time. To do the opposite of the consensus is to be **contrarian**.

In your example, the **projection** is the forecast.  When a recession occurs most participants will be gloomy in their outlook, however, your example is saying that there is **increased optimism** in projections which means most people (the consensus) do not think a recession will occur.

As a side note, the consensus can be horribly wrong at times, especially at turning points.

Answer (score 2):

To "call" something can be to predict it, or make a judgment on it.

For instance: if there is an election and the candidates seem to have a similar number of supporters, then people who predict elections might say that the election is **"too close to call"**.  But if candidate X is clearly ahead, even though the election hasn't happened it might be said that those making predictions are **"calling the election for candidate X"**.

The "consensus call" here is the "prevailing opinion on the likelihood of a recession".  Due to recent optimistic information, the consensus is *not* to "make the call" that there will be a recession.

*(Note: In finance terminology, there is another meaning of call... in terms of a kind of stock option:*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_option

*...but this isn't talking about that.)*